# Sending bulk emails when receiving an email from specific address

Tags: gratis, email, email-client, outlook, thunderbird

I want an email client that allow me to send bulk emails to around 200 recipient when it received an email with specific address, for example when the email client receive an email From the following address (test@example.com) I want it to resend the email to all the people in my address book.

I tried to set rules in both outlook and Thunderbird email client but the problem is the only option I have is to "Forward" not to "Resend" or "Send" the email and the problem here is that when any recipient receive an email, he/she can view all other emails that received my email.

Is there any  Free software or Plugin can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Mail Merge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/) for Thunderbird. It enables you to personalize mass mails by using variables, sent to many different recipients in your address book or a *.csv* file.

Comment: unfortunately this add-on doesn't work with filters

Comment: Which filters do you mean? That's a very generic term.

Answer (score 0):

You really want what is called a listserv.  A listserv serves...lists of people/emails.  Depending on how they are configured, you can control membership on the lists, sending rights, reply rights, approval of messages or pass through automatically, etc.

I'm a big fan of Free software, so I'd check out GNU Mailman - http://www.list.org/